# Strange results from interp3

Tags: matlab

I am using interp3 in matlab and getting some strange behavior. I want to get sub-voxel values in a 3D image, but I am getting incorrect values.

The following code creates a random 3D image. I am trying to extract a sub-pixel at the point (25,33,36). The interpolated value at this point should be equal (or very close) to the index at that point. But I am getting different values.

```
x = 25; y=33; z= 36;
c = [x,y,z]; 
sE2= randn(50,50,50);
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:size(sE2,1),1:size(sE2,2),1:size(sE2,3));
f = interp3(X,Y,Z,sE2,c(1),c(2),c(3),'linear')
v = sE2(c(1),c(2),c(3))
```

Output:

> f =
>
> 0.5166
>
> v =
>
> 0.2645

Obviously, this will give different values every time, but f and v should be the same or close, since I am interpolating an indexed value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order-of-coordinates confusion strikes again. While on the coordinate XY plane we list horizontal coordinate first and vertical second, in a matrix it's vertical first and horizontal second. Example: when you use `[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:3,1:2)`, the entries of X matrix are the column indices (listed second among indices) and the entries of Y are the row indices (listed first).

Long story short: the value you get from interpolation matches the entry

```
 v = sE2(c(2),c(1),c(3))
```

rather than

```
 v = sE2(c(1),c(2),c(3))
```

It's probably best to fix the preceding line: replace it with

```
f = interp3(X,Y,Z,sE2,c(2),c(1),c(3),'linear')
```

so that X goes with the second index and Y with first.